# How to FirstOrDefault() with Dapper

Tags: dapper

I am having problems returning a single object from a Dapper query. I have a simple query and I want to get the first object from the returned collection. What am I missing?

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
{
    string query = @"select * from order";
    sqlConnection.Open();

    // Works
    var orders = sqlConnection.Query<OrderModel>(query);

    // Does Not Work ERROR: "does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and 
    // no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' 
    // accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<OrderModel>'"
    var order = sqlConnection.Query<OrderModel>(query).FirstOrDefault();                                                                        
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? You need to give us more details...

Comment: why arent you doing `select top 1 * ...`?

Comment: Yeah I didn't see the error was in your comments. You are missing the System.Linq namespace reference as the answer bellow states...

Comment: FirstOrDefault is just regular LINQ - needs `using System.Linq;` at the top

Comment: Marko, I included the error in my code comments. Leppie, good point and that is probably what I'll do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are getting this error because you have not added the namespace

```
using System.Linq
```

in your cs file.